# Helvetica Neue appares different in the browser on Windows when locally installed than on Mac OS X. Why?

Tags: windows, macos, fonts

Tested on Windows XP, 7 and Mac OS X 10.5.8.

See the images, First is of airnewzealand.co.nz viewed on Google Chrome on Windows 7, 
[image]
the second is the same website viewed on the Mac in Safari. 
[image]
Why the massive boldness difference between the two fonts?

Helvetica Neue is installed locally on the Windows 7 PC's and I believe came with Mac OS X. Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

The third image is of the CSS for the fields in question.
[image]

Comment: The Windows / Chrome one sure looks _fuzzy_. Antialiasing gone wild?

Answer (score 2):

Mac and Windows display fonts differently. It has nothing to do with you its just how the render the fonts on the machine.

Read this link for more info

[Link](http://blog.fontslive.com/2010/11/web-fonts-quality.html)

Also the fonts are loading fine. It is not loading Helvetica after Helvetica Neue. They are both Helvetica Neue in both Chrome and Safari versions.

Comment: Also our maximum benefactor's favorite topic: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html  This is slowly disappearing with DirectWrite coming into vogue.

Comment: Thing is the font renders fine on Safari when viewed on the Windows PC's

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem sometimes before. This is because you are not having(in window's fonts directory) the "Helvetica Neue" font with Normal version. If you check your font directory you will see only "Helvetica Neue" with Bold Italic version there. It may be named as "HelveticaBlkIt.ttf".

As the normal font is missing there, the browser is using Bold Italic version.

If you have "Helvetica Neue" Normal font then install it OR simply delete that Bold Italic version from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly it isn't installed properly and it is just defaulting to the next font, in this cause Helvetica then Arial.

Comment: Helvetica does NOT look like that. The font its showing is Helvetica Block Italics

Answer (score 0):

It is a chrome bug. Lot of people are facing it. Usually happens due to various weights and styles of Helvetica installed locally. Permanent Solution is to Uninstall Helvetica (all types) and restart browser/computer.

Another solution is to use this Extension from chrome web store:

[Force Custom Fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%BD%91%E9%A1%B5%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

1. Install Extension
2. Settings > Extensions > Force Custom Fonts (Options)
3. Under Substitute Fonts, click +, add "Helvetica Neue" to "Arial"
4. Save and then Refresh the affected pages
5. Buy me a beer :P

ps: this is not the best possible solution but at least it doesn't make the page look ugly

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

On Windows, Helvetica family fonts do not exist by default. If you install Helvetica or Helvetica Neue, fonts of many web pages, even extensions will change in Google Chrome. They might become Bold, Italic or both.

**SOLUTION**

Step 1: Close Google Chrome

Step 2: Go to Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Fonts, Or go to: C:\Windows\Fonts

Step 3: Delete all Helvetica and Helvetica Neue fonts family

Step 4: Re-open Google Chrome

In this step the problem should be already fixed! If it is not, then the fonts still exist in the Windows Registry. So proceed to these additional steps:

Step 5: Close Google Chrome again,

Step 6: Run Registry Editor: Press Windows key + R to open Run dialog, Type regedit, then hit Enter.

Step 7: Navigate the following folder HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts.

Step 8: Select all Helvetica and Helvetica Neue fonts, Right-click on the highlighted fonts, then select Delete.

Step 9: Re-open Google Chrome

Now it is fixed :)