# Different browsers are using different fonts

Tags: css, fonts, chromium, webfonts

In CSS, I have something like this:

```css
.header {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</header>
```

I have tested this on different browsers, but the appearance of the text doesn't seem to be consistent. I had a look to see which system font the browsers have picked up. These are the results:

---

**Chrome** Version 121.0.6167.140 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Rendered Fonts

```
Family name: Helvetica Neue 
PostScript name: HelveticaNeue-Condensed
Font origin: Local file(15 glyphs)
```

---

**Edge** Version 121.0.2277.106 (Official build) (64-bit)

Rendered Fonts

```
Family name: Helvetica Neue 
PostScript name: HelveticaNeue-Condensed
Font origin: Local file(15 glyphs)
```

---

**Firefox** Version 115.7.0esr (32-bit)

Fonts Used

```
Helvetica Neue
HelveticaNeue-Medium
```

---

Firefox is the result I want. Helvetica Neue Condensed is like a variant of the Helvetica Neue. As a CSS developer, intuitively, I would only want to use "Helvetica Neue Condensed" if I specify `font-stretch: condensed;`

Just wonder if there is a workaround about making this consistent without supplying the font file online. I want users to stick with system fonts where possible.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: How are you looking up which are used? Because on my mac, where Helvetica Neue is preinstalled, it never looks like the condensed version by default...

Comment: it's not the answer you are looking for but if you want to make sure a very specific font type gets used whatever is the system loading the page and despite any font it has installed, you may use web fonts by [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) in your css that will map a `font-family` name to a given font asset that may also be an embedded font type given as base64. In your specific scenario is also strange a Windows machine is rendering Helvetica

Comment: Helvetica Neue is not installed by default on Windows systems, so I'm not sure why it would be considered a "system font"

Comment: See also [Helvetica Neue appares different in the browser on Windows when locally installed than on Mac OS X. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7733372/215552)

Comment: @somethinghere You can look up which font is actually used in the web developer tools. In Chrome, that will be DevTools. Select an element, then scroll down to the bottom in the "Computed" panel.

Comment: @DiegoD I appreciate that, but because of font licencing issue, I am not allowed to embed the font in this case.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Some people may choose to install Helvetica Neue manually, especially designers.

Comment: but yet you cannot grant the system has Helvetica installed.. especially Windows machines! it's very very rare indeed. So why using it as the font for your web contents? I know I shouldn't argue that.. because the actual question you asked is: why Firefox is using a different font type compared to Chrome and Edge given the same font family? I don't know.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand that the font displaying look different on Windows and Mac but that is not my concern here. It is pretty obvious that the browsers are using different fonts to display the same text with same CSS rules. Helvetica Neue and Helvetica Neue Condensed look very different.

Comment: @DiegoD Windows can't have Helvetica installed? There is a large pool of Windows-using designers and frontend developers who may have Helvetica installed. But that's not the point here... People can choose to install any font they want, and the same issue can happen to other fonts too.

Comment: there's still a chance that the difference among different choices made by each browser depends on their css defaults. Try comparing the computed value of font related css properties of the element and see if there's any difference. Maybe setting `font-weight: 500;` to override the default? maybe seeing what's going on with `font-stretch`?

Comment: @user2526586 yes of course anyone can do anything.. I'm just saying your audience is the entire pool and you are taking an explicit choice where only a small percentage will enjoy your content the way you expected them to do because of the conditions I explained before. I don't have the numbers but I'm sure that less than 1% of windows users has Helvetica installed.. maybe even much less than that. Anyway this is not the focus of your question. I respect that. It was worth pointing out but nothing more

Comment: @DiegoD I have just tried font-weight:normal, font-weight:500 and font-stretch to different values, but sorry to say that's not fixing the issue...

Comment: this is the very last attempt that comes to my mind: try using `font-family: "Helvetica Neue Medium", "Helvetica Neue"` and see if it has effect on Chrome or Edge in rendering the correct font instead of the condensed. Otherwise I'm out of ideas

Comment: @DiegoD Sorry, that doesn't work.

Comment: I know how to check, you just don't tell use in your question how you came up with those results as your method might be flawed. Note: Condensed does not appear if everything is set up correctly (like on a mac). How are you getting these fonts? Are you loading them on your system? Are you use @font-face? Are you fontface definitions definitely correct? No chance the wrong one is hooked up? No chance your system is confusing it? Please provide a minimal example so we can replicate the issue you are seeing.

Comment: @somethinghere Sorry, I don't think I understand you. As I mentioned "system font", this would be interpreted that the font was loaded from local system rather than web font, right? I didn't mention anything about @ font-face in the question, because, no, I didn't use that. Checking the rendered fonts on the developer tools on the browsers is the only method I know how to check the actual font chosen for the page. Please enlighten me. I don't understand how you want me to provide a minimal example. I thought the code above is self-explanatory. What kind of examples are you expecting?

Comment: Wow, you are a fun character. In that case, windows doesn't have Helvetica, so it can't render that anyway, no matter how you slice it. Then it's a wrong font install, in all likelihood. What I mean is: provide something that we can debug, because otherwise this just isn't a good question. Also, not commenting further here, your attitude is not very appealing.

Comment: @somethinghere wow, calm down. I literately did not understand your question. I was really asking you questions. I didn't mean anything rude or sarcasm. Please don't take it that way. I literately did not understand what kind of examples you were referring to. Maybe it's my wording that confused you my tone. Maybe because I was just trying to squeeze my sentences within the character limit. But, really, no rudeness was intended.

Comment: @somethinghere Since this is more like a problem how browsers behave. I have edited my question with Version numbers added. With the HTML and CSS quoted in my question, I really don't know what else I can provide you to help debugging. If there is some other info that may be helpful to resolve this issue, please let me know and I am happy to provide.

Comment: @somethinghere I am sorry if I have offended you anyway. But like I said, no rudeness or attitude intended. I was literately confused when you asked for minimal example because I really have got nothing else to show you, well, nothing that I know of that is related to this... No `@font-face` is used. No webfonts are used. I just used `font-family`.

Comment: A browser may select any font file it considers to be a suitable replacement. If you have installed a condensed Helvetica - the browser may also choose this for rendering as it doesn't autodetect whether its a regular or a condensed file. Besides, Helveticas often get mapped to Arial by default - which makes things even more unpredictable. In the end loading a custom font via `@font-face` is the only reasonable way to provide a consistent rendering. You'll find opensource lookalikes like TeX Gyre